# Display space in chart in case of null value present in object in high chart stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

```js
series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, null, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
```

For Example, in the above object, `"Jane"` contains null value as 4th parameter, so instead of not displaying the data we need to display space in between the grouped bars in chart

Comment: HighCharts Handle NULL Values as spaces by default: http://jsfiddle.net/fx47xhLr/

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code to replace null with empty string:

```
let obj = {
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, null, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
  }]
};

let obj1 = JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => {
  if (v === null) {
    return ""; // change null to empty string
  } else {
    return v; // return unchanged
  }
})

obj = JSON.parse(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

But making space will disturb chart readability. Now, one stacked bar has value 7 (0-7) on yAxis and the second one has value equal 2 (7-9) which shows them as a sum 9 on the chart. If you will make the space for the null value it will move the upper point higher.

The only solution which came to my mind (which is not perfect, because it disturbs the chart readability a little) is to set a point with really small value and white color and disabled showing this point in the tooltip.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xwbtk9yr/

```
series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, {y: 0.2, color: 'white', }, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
   }]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter